# How to move row data from 1 JTable to another?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, classcastexception

I'm trying to move the row data from one table to another by setting the model of the tables.

I'm getting the following error when I tried to `addRow()` to the `DefaultTableModel`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Should it be `Vector` or `Object`? Do I really need to cast it?

Here's my code.

```
int selectedRowIndex = subjectsListJtbl.getSelectedRow();
int selectedColIndex = subjectsListJtbl.getSelectedColumn();
DefaultTableModel curriculumSubjectsModel = (DefaultTableModel)curriculumSubjectsJtbl.getModel();
curriculumSubjectsModel.addRow((Object[])subjectsListJtbl.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColIndex));
curriculumSubjectsJtbl.setModel(curriculumSubjectsModel);
```

Also, could you provide some tips on how I can avoid adding duplication of the row data from one table to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add as an array

change to

```
curriculumSubjectsModel.addRow((Object[])
    {subjectsListJtbl.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColIndex)});
```

or as you hinted you can create a vector and add that.

Comment: That's exactly what I did on line 4 of my code but I don't know why I'm getting the error. Okay, let me try the vector.

Comment: No, line 4 of your code does NOT have the `{` and `}`

Comment: Oh my mistake. Sorry. Thanks. This solved my problem. I overlooked that array. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your code and the error you are getting this seems to be the cause for the error.

```
curriculumSubjectsModel.addRow((Object[])subjectsListJtbl.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColIndex));
```

Here you are taking a value from a cell in your table and casting it to an Object array. It is not possible cast an String object or any other object into an array object. So to fix this you can create an Object array with the desired value and pass it to the `addRow()` method.

```
curriculumSubjectsModel.addRow(new Object[]{subjectsListJtbl.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColIndex)});
```